# handle 404 error in ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: java, web-services, spring-integration

Is there away to handle 404 error in ws:outbound-gateway am using Spring integration 4.3.5 
error below,

> [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (jmsIn.container-1) Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) to the gateway; it allows you to handle the error, throw a different exception, or return some other reply.

See [here for a general discussion about adding advices to endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).