# How do I get the Spring Cloud Stream App Starter httpclient processor to send error messages from an api response to a log sink?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

When I check the stdout logs for my httpclient processor, I see that I'm getting a 422 response when I make requests. The actual error message sent with the response is lost, or at least I'm not sure how to get to it. Is it possible to send the json response to a log sink so that I can troubleshoot my request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RabbitMQ binder, you can configure the consumer to republish the failed message to a DLQ (`republishToDlq`); the failed message will include headers with exception information.

You can then add another stream to consume from the dlq...

```
:dest.dlq > log
```

For any binder, you could customize the http-client app to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` [as discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616060/handle-404-error-in-wsoutbound-gateway/44616229#44616229) to log the exception (or send it to another destination).